# KineticJS, animating specific objects/node within a layer

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm having trouble figuring out if what I want to do is possible and if so how to do it.

I have a bunch of shapes sorted out into 3 groups. Of these 3 groups, 1 of them contains objects that have their positions updated through animation. I'm also trying to allow for all the groups/objects to be draggable (their position relative to each other needs to stay the same, so right now I'm simply setting the layer they are in to be draggable).

The problem is that the animation has to redraw the entire layer, which contains ALL the objects. It seems unnecessary to be redrawing a bunch of shapes that aren't moving so I'd like to only animate objects within the one group. But I don't know how.

A general example of the structure I'm working with:

```
            Stage
              |
            Layer
              |
   +----------+----------+
   |          |          |
Group 1    Group 2    Group 3
```

Group 1 needs to be animated. All three groups need to be draggable. I've tried putting Group 1 in a layer and then add that layer to a parent layer, but that doesn't seem to work.

Very rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTcaL/

Comment: can I see ur code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I added an example into the original post. It's very basic compared to what I'm actually working with, but basically my code just has a lot more static and moving objects setup in the same way as the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this instead:

```
        Stage
          | 
   +------+------+
   |      |      |
 Layer  Layer   Layer
   |
 shapes
```

One of the great things about KineticJS is the ability to create as many layers as you want, and to group things together in different layers based on how often they are redrawn

Comment: The issue I ran into with this was that I want to be able to do 3 things: 1) Zoom (using .setScale), 2) drag, 3) animate. Animating requires a layer. There's a number of objects that don't to be animated so they could be in their own separate layer, and I could update that layer's position with onDragEnd (there was an example of that somewhere here on SO). But doing that then I couldn't figure out how to still zoom/scale all the layers. If it helps, the site with the actual code I have and am trying to change is: http://kurt1288.bitbucket.org/. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong?